# テーブルに保存されているのに、リロードするとビューがリセットされる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

※[他質問サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/2qxw4a2ewuhk5b)でも同様の質問をしています。解決した場合はそちらも更新します。よろしくお願いします。

#### 前提・実現したいこと

投稿された質問(post)に対して回答したコメント(comment)に非同期通信でいいね(good)を押す機能を実装したいです。

空のハートマークを押すと赤いハートに切り替わり、赤いハートを押すと空のハートマークに切り替わります。

DBは以下のように設計しています。
[image: イメージ説明]

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

いいねを押した後にリロードすると空のハートマークになってしまいます。
そのまま赤いハートに残っていて欲しいです。

**①いいね（空のハート）を押す前**
テーブルは空の状態です。
[image: イメージ説明]

**②いいねを押した後**
テーブルに作成され、赤いハートに切り替わります。
id:20, comment_id: 8, user_id: 1
[image: イメージ説明]

**③リロードした後（問題がある点）**
テーブルには作成されたままですが、空のハートになってしまいます。
[image: イメージ説明]

**④もう一度いいねを押す**
テーブルの中身は変わらず、赤いハートに切り替わります。
id:20, comment_id: 8, user_id: 1
[image: イメージ説明]

**⑤赤いハートを押す**
テーブルの中身は空になり、空のハートに切り替わります。
[image: イメージ説明]

#### 該当のソースコード

ビュー関連

```
app/views/goods/_good.html.erb

<% unless @comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank? %>
  <%= link_to post_comment_good_path(post_id: @post.id, id: comment.goods[0].id), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
    <div class="vertical_good">
      <%= image_tag "icon_red_heart.png", size: '20x20' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to post_comment_goods_path(@post, comment), method: :post, remote: true do %>
    <div class="vertical_good">
      <%= image_tag "icon_heart.png", size: '20x20' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```
app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

<div class="p-comment__item">
  <p><%= simple_format(comment.comment) %></p>
  <div class="p-comment__bottomLine">
    <div id="goods_buttons<%= comment.id %>">
      <%= render partial: 'goods/good', locals: { post: @post, comment: comment } %>
    </div>
    <span><%= comment.created_at.to_s(:datetime_jp) %></span>
    <span><%= link_to '削除', post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: '削除してよろしいですか？' } %></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
app/views/posts/show.html.erb

（省略）

<div class="p-comment__list">
  <div class="p-comment_listTitle">コメント</div>
  <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>

<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
```

```
app/views/goods/create.js.erb

$('#goods_buttons<%= @comment.id %>').html("<%= j(render partial: 'goods/good', locals: {comment: @comment}) %>");
```

```
app/views/goods/destroy.js.erb

$('#goods_buttons<%= @comment.id %>').html("<%= j(render partial: 'goods/good', locals: {comment: @comment}) %>");
```

コントローラ

```
goods_controller.rb

class GoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: %i[create destroy]

  def create
    @good = Good.create(user_id: current_user.id, comment_id: @comment.id)
  end

  def destroy
    good = Good.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, comment_id: @comment.id)
    good.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  end
end
```

モデル関連

```
comment.rb

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :goods, dependent: :destroy

  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }

  def good_user(user_id)
    goods.find_by(user_id: user_id)
  end
end
```

```
good.rb

class Good < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :comment_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

```
user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
（省略）
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :goods

（省略）
end
```

#### 自分で調べたことや試したこと

テーブルには保存されているので、comment.rbのgood_user(user_id)メソッドがおかしいかと思いましたが、特に間違いは見つけられず
そのメソッドを使用している_good.html.erbに問題があるのかと模索しましたが、わかりませんでした。

エラーメッセージが表示されているわけではないため原因の検討がつかず、知恵をお借りしたいです。

#### 使っているツールのバージョンなど補足情報

ruby: 3.0.2
rails: 6.0.4
jquery-rails: 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[他の質問サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/2qxw4a2ewuhk5b#reply-ar3strfbg4weoz)にて解決しました。ご協力ありがとうございました。

＜追記＞
`unless comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank?`と`link_to post_comment_good_path(post_id: @post.id, comment_id: comment.id, id: @current_user), method: :delete, remote: true do`に修正したところ実装できました。
条件分岐の読みにくさは別途修正します。

Answer (score 0):

`app/views/goods/_good.html.erb`にある`<% unless @comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank? %>`ですが、`@comment`や`@current_user`の中身を確認したほうがよいでしょう。`@comment`のidが8で`@current_user.id`が1なら動作しているはずですので、どちらかが期待通りになっていない可能性があります。

Comment: 引き続きありがとうございます！`<% unless @comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank? %>`の下に`<% binding.pry %>`を置き、デバッグしたところ、`@comment`はid:8、`@current_user.id`は1でした。他の可能性はありますでしょうか...`@comment.good_user(@current_user.id).blank?`の結果はfalseで、いいねを押した後のデバッグの検証も行おうとしましたが、応答せず取り急ぎ返信いたします。

Comment: Masafumi Okuraさん、ご協力ありがとうございました。他質問サイトにて問題が解決しました。